# I can't show AdMob banner in my application

Tags: java, android, admob

I trying to implement the AdMob banner in my app but it not showing. I already used the banners and i use always same way.. I have a `FrameLayout` with the view. This FrameLayout is inside a `LinearLayout`;

```
<FrameLayout
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"         
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"      
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >
    <com.google.ads.AdView 
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adUnitId="MyId"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:loadAdsOnCreate="true"/>
    </FrameLayout>
```

this is the java part:

```
adview = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
        adview.loadAd(new AdRequest());
```

and in the manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

with all meta-data:

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <activity
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: That i can't understand why it not appears. In any activity i try it doesn't showing.

Comment: @End.Game is it working now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing things up. You are using both old and new api with GoogleAdMobAdsSdk-6.4.1.jar. You should stick to the new api (admob via google play services). Make sure you don't have the GoogleAdMobAdsSdk-6.4.1.jar in your project's `/libs/` folder. Then, reference the google play services library within your project and make the following changes:

In your layout file, change:

```
  xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"

 <com.google.ads.AdView 
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adUnitId="MyId"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:loadAdsOnCreate="true"/>
```

to:

```
 xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

 <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adUnitId="MY_AD_UNIT_ID"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"/>
```

In your java code, change:

```
import com.google.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.ads.AdView;

adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());
```

to:

```
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;

adView.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder()
.build());
```

Just hit `Ctrl + Shift + O` to import to the right packages

You can also follow the official guide on migrating to the new admob [here](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/android/play-migration).

Make sure you use the google play services version 4 or later. You can check its manifest xml file for the versionCode. Thanks

Comment: ok wait..now i get this: The google play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resourses are included :( but however your explanation is perfect

Comment: Just make sure you import the play services library(Select 'copy to workspace' when importing) and reference it. Do a Project->Clean and use the right api as provided in answer. It should work then. Don't forget to upvote/accept answer

Comment: You're my savior! It works :) thanks. Sorry for late! :)

Answer (score 0):

change from `com.google.ads.AdView` to `com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView`

Comment: Well now i have a crash.. `NoSuchMethodError: com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest` at line `adview.loadAd(new AdRequest());`

Comment: May be...You also imported that `google-admob.jar` file... remove that library it will work...

Comment: Check logcat..maybe ad is loading but it is not able to show...Then change `Framelayout` to `LinearLayout`

Comment: Ok tell me..but still not work.. The log says: `An error occurred in AdLoader` ... but not says which error

Comment: In FrameLayout lastChild will be an overlay.. you have to specify where you have to show the child i.e top,bottom,center etc...

Comment: mmh..but could be the play services library the problem? it's the first time i import it..

Comment: I think you are using `google-admob.jar` library..Go to `javabuildpath` check the private libraries there..

Comment: I'm using this one `GoogleAdMobAdsSdk-6.4.1.jar`

Comment: @End.Game, That's deprecated. You should get rid of that and use the google play services library instead. Check my answer

Comment: Yes that's deprecated that's why you are getting error..Import [playservices](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html#add-library)